# what is the usage of ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext) method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In a webapi/mvc Controller, a `Controller` will return a `ActionResult<T>` type,  and it has a `ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method.

What is the usage of `ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method?
How the MVC will used the method? And in it,  where  is the `ActionContext` parameter from? from the `Http` request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the usage of `ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method?

1. `IActionResult` is **the result (object) returned by your controller action method**. ASP.NET Core executes this result by invoking the `IActionResult::ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method.
2. Action method might return different kinds of `IActionResult`, such as **`JsonResult`** (which sends a json to client when executed), **`BadRequestResult`**(which sends `400` response when executed) and so on.
3. You can also create your own implementation of `IActionResult`. Just be aware that the `ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method **should write bytes to the HTTP Response** . For example, I created a [custom `IActionResult` to return CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492851/10091607) for your reference. This is a simple implementation that doesn't contains too much complicated logic.

   Some action results are rather complicated that they introduce a new `IActionResultExecutor<TResult>` interface to deal with these process, for example, the `ObjectResult` employ an `IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>` to do that. When creating your own implementation, whether to use an `IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>` is up to you.

> How the MVC will used the method?

1. WebApp developers don't need to invoke this`IActionResult::ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method manually. This is a method that will be invoked by the MVC/RazorPage subsystem.
2. If you're interested, the whole process is:

   - a coming request received
   - match current request against the pre-defined routes (route table or graph). If matched :

     - we know the controller name, action name, and other route data.
     - Since we've known the controller name and action name, ASP.NET Core generates an instance of `ActionDescriptor` that describes the target C# action method, such as the parameters.
   - Since ASP.NET Core has known the Controller/Action and routes data, it creates an instance of **`IActionInvoker`** to invoke that action method pipline (including the filters, for more details, see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1)):

     - Action Method returns an instance of `IActionResult`
     - Before invoking the `IActionResult::ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)`, invoke Result Filters `OnResultExecuting()` method.
     - invoke `IActionResult::ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)`
     - After that, invoke the Result Filters `OnResultExecuted()` method.

> *where is the ActionContext parameter from? from the Http request?*

Firstly, `HttpContext` is built by the underlying server. It contains a `Request` property that mimics the HTTP Request.

Next, we'll get another two objects after selecting the action:

- `RouteData`: the route data, e.g. current `area` name, current `page` name, e.t.c.
- `ActionDescriptor`: a description about the current action that are matched with current route.

With the above three objects, ASP.NET Core creates the `ActionContext` by simply new it. For example, the `IRouter`-based Routing system creates an actionContext as below:( [see source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/MvcRouteHandler.cs#L69-L78))

```
// create action context
var actionContext = new ActionContext(context.HttpContext, routeData, actionDescriptor);

// create action invoker
var invoker = _actionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(actionContext);
if (invoker == null){ throw ...;}

// invoke the pipeline
return invoker.InvokeAsync();
```